# SELECT statement based on another select statement

Tags: php, sql, select

I am looking to carry out a select statement based on another select statement.

```
SELECT descrip FROM `weather` WHERE DATE(date_time) = CURDATE()
```

SELECT * FROM clothing WHERE userid=$userid AND weathertag LIKE "%descrip%"

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow

you can use "JOIN" statment as [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) said, but my suggestion is:

SELECT * FROM clothing WHERE userid=$userid AND weathertag LIKE (SELECT descrip FROM `weather` WHERE DATE(date_time) = CURDATE())